# positioning a div right and left simultaneously

Tags: html, css, positioning

i'm trying to make a div have a width using the absolute positioning and it work fine in google chrome but in fierfox it doesnt. why is there a conflict ? i tried the exact same code in both browser and on fierfox doesnt reconize it.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Kelma</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

            <input type="text" id="center" />
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the css file

```
#center{
    position: absolute;
    left:50px;
    right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK input does not have a width, it belongs to inline elemens

Comment: That looks right to me; I'm not sure why it's failing. If it's not working in Firefox, what is it doing wrong?

Comment: @caligula: Uh, I've definitely put widths on text input elements before. How else are you supposed to set the width of your text boxes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [html <input> element ignores CSS left+right properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450316/html-input-element-ignores-css-leftright-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Kelma</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <style>
            #wrapper
            {
               position: absolute;
               left:50px;
               right: 50px;
            }
            #center
            {
               width:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
               <input type="text" id="center" value="test" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i wrapper the input with a div, and i applied the styling to the div, and 100% width to the input.

Comment: I believe the original code wasn't working in FF because of the way textbox widths and positions are handled.  By wrapping it, you force the width to adjust.

Comment: thank you now it's woking but why ?! i really want to understand why not on fierfox.

Comment: From what I tried, <INPUT> absolute positioning works strangely across browsers when you set both left and right offsets (to a value greater than zero), even if you force width:auto.. when you try to do the same with DIVs or even inline-block elements, then it works... it's quite odd to me, but that is what I've found..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#center{
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I position stuff on both sides all the time. Is it something specific to text boxes that makes them not want to resize to fit?

Comment: @marcelo what you are showing in your example means that the width will be 100% + 50px, which will cause the element to get out of bounds (so it will be cropped or there will be scrolls, or it will cause some other issues that i cant remember at the moment).

Comment: Ops, a little carelessness. Thanks @trajce

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work with inline css

here is an example from my personal website

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:60px; bottom:5%; left:5%; right:5%; width:90%; text-align:center;"> SOME TEXT </div>
```

I personally like to use the percent as it can look better on some sites. Let me know if this works for you! To see it live: http://cbogausch.com/portal It works in both firefox and chrome

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you mean?

```
body{padding: 0 50px;}
input{width:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your css:

```
#center {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
}
```

Hgs,
Vinicius =)