# Strange behaviour when absolute positioning an INPUT with both left and right CSS properties

Tags: html, css, layout, cross-browser

I'm studying the CSS formatting of an absolutely positioned `<input>`.
I'd like it to "stretch" inside its container (which is also positioned "absolute") so that it leaves for instance 30px both left and right, and fills all the space within...

I already found a [sample on w3.org site](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolutely-positioned), which uses both left and right to create a kind of "frameset" in CSS.

I also read [an article from A-List-Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/conflictingabsolutepositions) talking about this kind of technique and found several other questions here dealing similar troubles, but none of these focuses the specific issue I'm going to describe. I also found that I can wrap the inner `<input>` with a `<div>`, but I'd like to dig a bit more on this subject to understand why it is misbehaving...

Here is [a working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ws9hf/6/) I made to test and clarify the idea.
In short it is something as simple as this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <input type="text" value="input" />
</div>
```

with a style like this:

```
body { height: 100% } /* Required for percentage heights below */
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 160px;
}
#sidebar input {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 21px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    width: auto;
}
```

The interesting point is on the last three lines, when I set left and right and leave width as "auto".

The outcome is that it only works as expected using Chrome (v.26), but in FF.20 or IE.10 it looks broken: the `<input>` extends beyond the right margin of its container div.. much the same you get when putting width:100% and only settings left position...

The funny part is that this approach with DIVs and inline-block SPANs works as expected across all three browsers.

Is it a bug on browsers' side? Is there a way to make it work without the workaround to enclose `<input>` with width:100% inside another `<div>` positioned in the described way?

Hope that someone has a clue on this.

PS: I'm focusing on "modern", html5 browsers, so I don't mind if it won't work on IE8 or older..

Comment: what comes to mind when you want a element to behave like anotter type of element is perhaps make it behave like such element by giving it the same properties, that being said, what i mean is make it `display:block`for starters and see where that takes you

Comment: I've already tried it and (of course) it wasn't so easy, but you're right: never overlook simple things :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Observations

I'm surprised by this behavior. top-right-bottom-left absolute positioning works marvelously (and has for years) but it's ignored by IE 10 and FF on `input type="text"`

Red herring: your approach *does* work with `input type="range"` but not `input type="number"` in IE 10. Perhaps this is related to which inputs the browser takes sole responsibility for drawing, versus those inputs that may thinly wrap functionality already provided by the OS.

In FF (PC/Mac) I observed that the `size` property of the input seems to override anything but an explicit width assignment. For example, setting `size=4` will make the input more narrow than desired. The observed width seems to be the result of an implicit `size=20` value.

### Workarounds

All that said, I do have a potential solution which doesn't require extensive changes to your code and works in IE9/10, FF (PC/Mac), Chrome (PC/Mac) and Safari (Mac).

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ws9hf/13/

```
#sidebar .x {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 60px);
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px; /* fallback */
}
```

This uses the [cacl() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) which has [decent browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc). It's worth noting that this feature is deemed "at risk" by the W3, so its future may be uncertain.

As "cool" as the `calc()` function is—being pragmatic—I'd probably wrap the offending input(s) in another element and be done with it. You'll achieve wider browser support, and future compatibility.

Comment: I agree, the point is probably what the browser do to render `<input>` controls: if they are drawed by the OS, then probably there might be some strange glitch on the browser-OS side, which -apart from probably being a bug- could explain their different behaviour...

Comment: When `left` & `right`, then using **`width: calc(100% - leftVal - rightVal)`** will expand the `input` element like regular `div`

Comment: By far the best solution which doesn't involve any wrapper element, with which other issues like padding & border will come (ex: try applying padding in `%` - if applied to wrapper, then it won't be padding for the `input`. If you apply to input, then the `%` values will be calculated based on wrapper width which is not the expected)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the input inside a container div, and perform the styling on that div.
here is an example

```
<div id="sidebar">
     <div id="inputContainer">
         <input type="text" value="input" />
     </div>
</div>

body { height: 100% } /* Required for percentage heights below */
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 160px;
}
#sidebar #inputContainer {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 21px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}
#inputContainer{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly what you asked, but if you only care about modern browsers, you can use flexbox instead.

You just need to specify that you are using flexbox and want a vertical direction, then you can set a margin of 30px, rather than using positioning:

```
#sidebar {
    /* stripped out additional styles and prefixes */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#sidebar x {
    margin: 0 30px;
}
```

See the demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ws9hf/8/

Comment: in FF (latest official version so far, v.20.0.1) your sample doesn't work as expected (`input` goes out of the green bar).. Anyway this is another path I'd like to study a bit more =)